# Rails 4 using validations on DateTime to get shoulda test passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, datetime, rspec, shoulda

Of the following tests:

```
  it { should have_valid(:date_time).when ("2014/April/15") }
  it { should_not have_valid(:date_time).when ("2014/April/15000") }
  it { should_not have_valid(:date_time).when ("2014/ZZZ/14") }
  it { should_not have_valid(:date_time).when(nil, '') }
```

the following two are not passing:

```
  it { should_not have_valid(:date_time).when ("2014/April/15000") }
  it { should_not have_valid(:date_time).when ("2014/ZZZ/14") }
```

I'm getting the error message `argument out of range` for both. In my model, I have the following:

```
class Textmessage < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :date_time, presence: true
end
```

What would I need to add to my validations to get this to pass?

Comment: Not clear. Are you asking for something that will validate against a range of dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior from shoulda. Rails will raise an exception when given either of those strings for a DateTime column, not set an error on the model.